# Offset bell curves that sum to a fixed value

Tags: interpolation

I'm in need of a well studied bell curve function $f(x)$ that satisfies the following equation:

> $\exists P,\!C \; \forall x \:\left(\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x+i P)}\right)=C$

That is; an infinite set of them offset by some fixed interval sums to the same value everywhere.

[[**NOTE:** if this is a well studied field, I seem to be unable to figure what terms to lookup to do my own research. I'd welcome just being pointed at a search term I can use to answer this on my own. That would likely be more valuable than an answer to the question I'm actually asking here.]]

Ideally I'd like a function that:

- Has a maximum at zero.
- Is monotonic going away from zero.
- Is positive everywhere.
- Is continuous and continuously differentiable.
- Is symmetric around zero.

---

I'm looking to do interpenetration from periodic samples, but wants something that has different properties than a Taylor series (no divergence to infinity) or a discreet Fourier transform (an assumption of being periodic). Also I need it to be highly local: altering a sample value should have rapidly diminishing effects away from that value.

---

Off hand the only thing I'm coming up with is this form of function:

> $f(x) = tan^{-1}(x+\frac{P}{2}) - tan^{-1}(x-\frac{P}{2})$

The same thing using a logistics curve or some other function with similar shape would also work.

Comment: "[Partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity)" isn't an exact fit for what you want.  In a partition of unity, at any point, only finitely many functions are nonzero.  So such a partition is an answer to your question, but there could be answers that are not partitions of unity.

Comment: Raised cosine window as sometimes used in overlap-add DFT resynthesis springs to mind.

Comment: @EricTowers : cool! In practice I don't think that difference is a problem: numerically, the set will always be truncated anyway.